# Extract Wikipedia Infobox data

Tags: java, eclipse, wikipedia

I want to extract the data from wikipedia infobox and came upon the code in [Wikipedia infobox extraction in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063158/wikipedia-infobox-extraction-in-java) that suggests a method to do so with java. I am not handy with java as I am with python so I am using the wikixmlj-r43.jar in my eclipse with the code :

```
import edu.jhu.nlp.wikipedia.*;
public class InfoboxParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        WikiXMLParser parser = WikiXMLParserFactory.getSAXParser("/home/siddhartha/Documents/wiki/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml");
        parser.setPageCallback(new PageCallbackHandler() {
            public void process(WikiPage page) {
                InfoBox infobox=page.getInfoBox();
                //do something with info box
            }
        });
        parser.parse();
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/bzip2/CBZip2InputStream
    at edu.jhu.nlp.wikipedia.WikiXMLParserFactory.getSAXParser(WikiXMLParserFactory.java:15)
    at parser.InfoboxParser.main(InfoboxParser.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.bzip2.CBZip2InputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
```

I have added the JAR in eclipse under properties > java build path > libraries. What I get is that it is not able to find CBZip2InputStream class.

Please help.

Comment: Not an answer to you specific question, but there is a fair chance that both WikiData and DBPedia have already done the job for you, and all you have to do is get it from their API.

Comment: I tried DBpedia but it is not as updated. Also I downloaded the raw infobox from DBpedia and loaded it in stardog. I check for triples against coldplay, but there were none even though coldplay has its infobox. I am not sure about WikiData though. I would appreciate if you can point me in that direction.

Comment: What infoboxes are you interested in?

Comment: I want infoboxes of all bands and musicians. Specifically those present on musicbrainz. Even though I know they are not all there. because musicbrainz takes its data from other sources except DBpedia and wikipedia. But, Atleast the one's that are there.

Comment: Then you have [plenty of poroperties](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q524114) on WikiData, eg P21 (gender), P434 (MusicBrainz artist ID), P569 (birthdate), P19 (borthdate) etc, etc, etc

Comment: I am not really familiar with WikiData. How did you get that?

Comment: Just look a band or musician up there!

Comment: Oh Yeah! Do they have an API to extract these results? because I was looking at the jar they developed but the documentation is not very descriptive. Is there a way I can get this data to my local machine.

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Wikibase/API

Comment: I have been trying different combinations of the API sandbox and it does not give the infobox data as eloquently as the search in the "search" field of wikidata gives. There are bits and pieces only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon")
            .execute();

    String html = res.body();

    Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
    Element body = doc.body();
    Elements tables = body.getElementsByTag("table");// hasClass("infobox bordered");

    for (Element table : tables) {

        if (table.className().equalsIgnoreCase("infobox bordered")) {
            System.out.println(table.outerHtml());
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

https://code.google.com/p/wikixmlj/source/browse/trunk/tests/InfoBoxTest.java?spec=svn40&r=40

Replace the link in the code(data/newton.xml) with this

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles=***your_title***&rvsection=0